# chrome devtool ext. receive postMessage

Tags: google-chrome-extension, postmessage, manifest.json

I'm trying to send over a json-formatted object from my React-application to my chrome-extension devtool. In my React application I have a method that runs `window.postMessage(data, '*')`. I'm really not sure what the relation is between the background.js and content-scripts.
I'm able to receive this data through content-scripts.js by adding `window.addEventListener('message')` but I don't get how to send this data over to my devtools.js

### manifest.json

```json
{
    "name": "visualize-test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "testing chrome-ext order of execution",
    "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
    "scripts": [
        "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
    },
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
    ],
    "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "file:///*"
    ]
}
```

This is the script file I'm injecting into my devtools.html

### devtools.js

```js
chrome.devtools.panels.create("visualize-test", null, "devtools.html", () => {
    const port = chrome.extension.connect({
        name: "visualize-test"
    })
    port.onMessage.addListener(data => {
        console.log('RECEIVING DATA IN CONTENT-SCRIPTS: ', data)
    }
    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (e) {
        console.log('DEVTOOLS MESSAGE HANDLER: ', e)
    })
})
```

### content-scripts.js

```js
window.addEventListener('message', e => {
    chrome.extension.sendMessage(e, (message) => {
        console.log('Received message..sending to chrome extension: ', e.data)
    })
})
```

### background.js

```js
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
    console.log('Connected to PORT: ', port)
    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender) {
        console.log('BACKGROUND.JS: ', message)
        port.postMessage(message)
    })

    port.onDisconnect.addListener(function (message) {
        console.log('PORT DISCONNECTED')
    })
})
```

I'm not ever receiving data from my background.js or the devtools.js after my data handler in content scripts runs `chrome.extension.sendMessage()`

Comment: See [the example in the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools#solutions).